# How to maintain a Python project made with venv in version control

Tags: python, python-3.x, version-control, python-venv

As a *Python3* newbie, I made use of `venv` to create a project, and the created project directory structure is like this:

- bin
- include
- lib
- lib64 (link to lib)
- penv.cfg
- share

The next step is to store this project into a version control system like `git`. As a Java programmer working on *maven* project, storing `pom.xml` to version control is enough. So I feel a bit unworthy to store all these subdirectories to the version control

**Question: Should I store all these files into the Version Control? If not, which of them to store in version control?**

Comment: `pipenv` and `Pipfile{,.lock}` were created to try solving this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yout hint :) I watched a Youtube tutorial about `pipenv`. There is the `Pipfile`, so `Pipfile` is like the `pom.xml` in maven project that it can be saved into verson control?  At least to my understanding it looks sth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store them in `.git` is unnecessary, if someone wants to have the same environment as you for example, you just want to make sure that they get the same `requirements.txt` file (packages that were installed by Python packet manager `pip`)

The bottom line is that to throw virtual environment in the gitignore and just have `requirements` file which is generated by `pip freeze >> requirements.txt` (you can name whatever you want but it is a convention to name it `requirements`

Comment: btw, I checked the generated `requirements.txt`. The Python version is not listed there. So with pure `venv`, is it possible to get the Python version somewhere?

Comment: No you cant have python version in `requirements.txt` , because `pip` is not installing Python. the only intuitive place where you can put Python version is in `README.md`

Comment: I read the generated `pyvenv.cfg` just now. There is python version there and I opened the generated project with Pycharm, seems that Pycharm is able to recognize the Python version through `pyvenv.cfg`. Is it so?

Comment: So is it necessary to store `pyvenv.cfg` to version control?

Comment: No, there is just no need to store that, anything that is associated with virtual environment should be ignored in the version control. Python version should be noted in instructions, and project should have a proper list of dependencies (`requirements.txt`). so that everyone could be on the right track.